# Prove that if $f(0) = 1, f'(0) < 0$ and $f''(0) < 0$ for all $x > 0$, then in the range of $(0, +\infty)$, there exists a unique c such that f(c) = 0.

Tags: calculus

Prove that if $f(0) = 1, f'(x) < 0$ and $f''(x) < 0$ for all $x > 0$, then in the range of $(0, +\infty)$, there exists a unique c such that f(c) = 0. This is rather obvious but I couldn't prove it.

Comment: The for all $x>0$ is throwing me off. You haven't shared a property with an $x$ involved, you only shared specified values of $x$.

Comment: @user2675516 please correct the exercise.

Comment: @UserX typed wrongly

Answer (score 1):

As $f''(x)<0$, note that $f(x)=f(0)+f'(\theta x)x<f(0)+f'(0)x,\theta\in(0,1),\forall x\in(0,+\infty)$, so $f(x)<0$ when $x>-\frac{f(0)}{f'(0)}$, then there exist some $c$ such that $f(c)=0$.

As $f'(x)<0$, $c$ is unique.

Comment: i don't quite understand your first line after note that

Comment: @user2675516 It is the mean value theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem together with the fact that $f'$ is strictly decreasing.